# Terraform wants to delete resources I did not specify to delete

Tags: terraform

I am running terraform plan on my resources and noticed that terraform wants to delete four resources. These resources are odd in the sense I am not aware of creating them specifically, although I did create resources with that specific name. What I mean is that the resources to be delete has the HTTP method == OPTION, where all my resources are GET/POST. The resource does exist then in a way but different from how I set it up. I am aware that options are used for pre flight checks from the browser and I am unsure how it is related. Here is an example of what one of the  the deletions look like. They all share the same http_method=OPTIONS.

```
> # module.RESOURCENAME.aws_api_gateway_integration._ will be destroyed
>   - resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "_" {
>       - cache_key_parameters = [] -> null
>       - cache_namespace      = "zsfbtm" -> null
>       - connection_type      = "INTERNET" -> null
>       - http_method          = "OPTIONS" -> null
>       - id                   = "agi-234cjz85m3-zsfbtm-OPTIONS" -> null
>       - passthrough_behavior = "WHEN_NO_MATCH" -> null
>       - request_parameters   = {} -> null
>       - request_templates    = {
>           - "application/json" = jsonencode(
>                 {
>                   - statusCode = 200
>                 }
>             )
>         } -> null
>       - resource_id          = "zsfbtm" -> null
>       - rest_api_id          = "234cjz85m3" -> null
>       - timeout_milliseconds = 29000 -> null
>       - type                 = "MOCK" -> null
>     }
```

What would the reason for these deletions be?

Comment: It was probably added to the code somewhere else and applied without you knowing about it. If you are using some version control system, make sure you pull the latest changes before running apply.

Comment: @MarkoE I think you are correct. I had a look and I can see it in the API gateway(but not in the code). I believe this was added manually to the gateway meaning that drift occurred and terraform will overwrite the manually added resources?

Comment: Those kind of changes are usually denoted with a message like "Changes happened outside of terraform". Not sure how are you dealing with the state file, but if those changes are applied locally and you don't have access to that state file, the one you have will be used as a reference.

Comment: Terraform is telling you here that there is a resource in the Terraform state, that was created via Terraform at some point, or imported into Terraform at some point, that is now no longer in the Terraform code, so it is doing to delete it. The API Gateway integration wasn't created manually in the AWS console, it was created via Terraform. Drift detection would show changes to a terraform managed resource, it wouldn't trigger deletion of a resource that was never managed by Terraform in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. I suspect a git merge must have removed something it should not have. I updated my terraform to the version that support the message "Changes happened outside of terraform" and since I see nothing, I will dig deeper before I deploy anything.

Comment: I think this might perhaps be a slightly older version of Terraform that might not support the "Changes outside of Terraform" message, because I also notice it doesn't have the extra hint line after "... will be destroyed" giving a reason for why Terraform is proposing to destroy, which was added only in a relatively recent version of Terraform (v1.2 I think... or perhaps v1.3.)